# Получение данных из XHR запроса Python

Tags: python, парсер, xhr

Для парсинга сайта необходимо получить ID всех товаров, находящихся на странице запроса. Сам сайт не дает спарсить ссылки, в которых находится ID. При таком парсинге выводиться пустая страница. Узнал про XHR запросы и у меня получилось получить ссылку, в которой должны храниться ID [image: ID, которые мне нужно вытащить по ссылке] [Вот сама ссылка (Копировал в консоли разработчика как cURL)](https://wbxsearch.wildberries.ru/exactmatch/v3/common?appType=1&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&curr=rub&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&emp=0&lang=ru&locale=ru&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&query=%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB6%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB5%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBD%5E%25%5ED1%5E%25%5E81%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBA%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB0%5E%25%5ED1%5E%25%5E8F%5E%25%5E20%5E%25%5ED1%5E%25%5E88%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB5%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBB%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBA%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBE%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB2%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB0%5E%25%5ED1%5E%25%5E8F%5E%25%5E20%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBF%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB8%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB6%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB0%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBC%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB0%5E%25%5E20%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB7%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB5%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBB%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB5%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EBD%5E%25%5ED0%5E%25%5EB0%5E%25%5ED1%5E%25%5E8F&reg=0&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,48,22,1,66,31,40,71&resultset=catalog&sort=popular&spp=0&stores=117673,122258,122259,125238,125239,125240,6159,507,3158,117501,120602,120762,6158,121709,124731,159402,2737,130744,117986,1733,686,132043)
Помогите пожалуйста достать ID по этому запросу.
Пытался сделать так

```
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers); print(r.text)
```

Но на выходе получил

```
>>> {}
```

Comment: Один раз получилось получить на выходе словарь с нужными ID, но к сожалению этот код был утерян.

Comment: https://suppliers-api.wildberries.ru/swagger/index.html

Comment: @Namerek, через API WB нельзя посмотреть ссылки на товары на странице по ключевому запросу, а мне необходимо именно это

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовался сайтом https://curlconverter.com/#python. Ввел в него cURL (bash) и получил готовый код.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).